# Dynamically override Bootstrap CSS variables in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

So what I have is a React project with `Bootstrap.css` loaded. I'd like to somehow override the variables, so for instance I have a bunch of buttons like

`<button className="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>`

Which basically 'inherit' the color from:

```
:root {
  --primary: somecolor;
}
```

Is there a way to somehow override this? I've tried passing it in as inline style to components, like `<Component style={{"--primary" : "red"}} />` which will override the `:root { --primary }`, but the button colors will remain the same. What's the easiest way to do this, considering I'm supporting dynamic colors, so I can't create a few CSS files, and it would be good if I didn't have to rewrite every single button I have to be a `styled-component` that minds props!

Comment: Can you use SASS?

Comment: I can, but wouldn't that recompile on each change of colors? Would prefer to do it runtime if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really an easy way to do this. You could generate the CSS for the "custom" primary colors in SASS, and then add a "root" primary color class to the component like this...

SASS to generate "primary" color Bootstrap CSS

```
/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "bootstrap";

@mixin build-primary-classes($color) {
    /* background classes */
    @include bg-variant(".bg-primary", $color);
    
    /* btn classes */
    .btn-primary {
        @include button-variant($color, $color);
    }
  
    .btn-outline-primary {
        @include button-outline-variant($color);
    }
    
    /* text- classes */
    @include text-emphasis-variant(".text-primary", $color);
    
    /* badge classes */
    .badge-primary {
        @include badge-variant($color);
    }
    
    /* borders */
    .border-primary {
        border-color: $color !important;
    }
}

$customprimarycolors: (
  "purple": purple,
  "red": red,
  "orange": orange
);

@each $colorName, $color in $customprimarycolors {
  .#{$colorName} {
    @include build-primary-classes($color);
  }
}
```

JS

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return( 
        <div className={this.props.className}>Hello <button className="btn btn-primary">Button</button></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello className="red" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Codeply demo: https://codeply.com/go/R4X5x8taiH

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but an idea... 
Could you edit your bootstrap.css file like this
    :root { --primary: unset; }

That way you wouldn't have to overwrite any bootstrap styles?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to use a provided method for theming, but yeah, I could go ahead and swap all `.*-primary` colors I guess! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**HONESTLY** ... I am not sure if it is a good idea to try to overwrite in CSS a few part of the classes bootstrap builds on a color var like `$primary` but let's the rest of the classes build on the same var as it is.

That's the way trouble raises up ...

An IMHO better way would be to do it the way Bootstrap provides it:

Changing in SASS the basic var `$primary` to the new wanted color in Bootstrap the color will change and the classes are there. Or adding a new color `$additional-color` and adding the color to map `$theme-color` and all the additional classes are build up on the fly ... Just have a look to the docs ... it is much more easier than it seems to be on the first look:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/color/

So yes: in SASS theming is possible just setting/adding the color vars.

But if in a project it is not possible to use SASS or the direct setup is not wanted for some reasons ... there are many free easy to use theming tools in the web which do the job for you. Than you are able to import a clean and consistend Bootstrap CSS with your wanted colors. Because that it is as easy Bootstrap is as successful (what not means I/you need to like it). As Bootstrap 5 still is Beta here an example for BS4 ...

http://pikock.github.io/bootstrap-magic/app/index.html#!/editor

---

*NOTE: only changing/overwriting the CSS color vars in CSS file is not enough as the colors in the classes are hard coded to the original hex colors. You indeed would have to overwrite the original classes which leads to doubled code structures.*